# NGINX redirect all to https://www.example.com except one folder

Tags: nginx, whmcs

I am running whmcs billing system using NGINX, my whmcs location is in mydomain.com/whmcs/

I want to redirect all request to my site to HTTPS www except whmcs folder (whmcs has its HTTPS redirection)

Some whmcs pages is redirected to HTTP by whmcs itself (knowledge, announcements page) and else in HTTPS

My current config

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {  
      return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  location /whmcs/ {} 
}
```